# Concurrently Add Nodes to Linked List golang

Tags: go, concurrency, linked-list

I'm trying to add nodes to a linked list concurrently using channels and goroutines. I seem to be doing be something wrong, however. Here's what I've written so far.

Currently, my print function is just repeating the 8th node. This seems to work on other linked lists, so I don't totally understand the issue. Any help would be great. Here is the code that I wrote

```
func makeNodes(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan Node) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        tmp := Node{Data: i, Next: nil}
        ch <- tmp
    }
    <-ctx.Done()
    return
}

type Node struct {
    Data int
    Next *Node
}

type List struct {
    Head   *Node
    Length int
    Last   *Node
}

func (l *List) addToEnd(n *Node) {
    if l.Head == nil {
        l.Head = n
        l.Last = n
        l.Length++
        return
    }
    tmp := l.Last
    tmp.Next = n
    l.Last = n
    l.Length++
}

func (l List) print() {
    tmp := l.Head
    for tmp != nil {
        fmt.Println(tmp)
        tmp = tmp.Next
    }
    fmt.Println("\n")
}

func main() {
    cha := make(chan Node)
    defer close(cha)

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    list := List{nil, 0, nil}
    go makeNodes(ctx, &wg, cha)

    go func() {
        for j := range cha {
            list.addToEnd(&j)
        }
    }()

    cancel()
    wg.Wait()

    list.print()
}
```

Comment: Your loop `for j:=` repeatedly overwrites `j` with each new element and re-adds the same element to the list (which corrupts the list).  try `addToEnd(&Node{Data: j.Data})` to force it to make a new instance each time.

Comment: Note "concurrently adding nodes" implies multiple threads are modifying the list, and will need locking/synchronization.   This code does not access the list concurrently.  The concurrency is only between the thread that produces data, and the thread the modifies the list.

Comment: How are you ensuring that the list has been fully updated by the time you're calling `list.print()`?

Comment: @Dave Sorry if I was using the wrong terminology. It seemed like it was running concurrently since i had a goroutine running. How would I creating locking and synchronization? This was just a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish in a larger program

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem wouldn't that be taken care of by the ```wg.Wait()``` line? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but to my understanding, that line makes the code wait until the goroutine is finished before it continues to further lines

Comment: @Grant no it won't. `makeNodes` decrements the waitgroup once it returns. the routine consuming the channel however will never return. The channel doesn't get closed, and there is no way to guarantee that, between the context getting cancelled & `list.print` being called that the `list.addElement` call will have returned.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Should I make another function similar to makeNodes that uses context and a waitgroup then for adding to the list? Or is there another way I can go about that?

Comment: @Grant With respect to concurrency, yes, you have concurrency, but you title implies that multiple threads are concurrently modifying the list, which is not the case.  Look into pkg sync.RWLock() and ensure that for example `addToList()` has a RWLock before modifying the list, and `print` has a read lock before accessing the list.

Comment: @Dave how would something like this look? https://go.dev/play/p/D4jbYxAmbj4

Comment: @Grant  Close.  Before modifying the list, you need a WRITE lock.  See https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex.Lock
"Read" locks allow many threads to get access to a lock for the purposes of reading only.  A "Write" lock will wait until all the readers have unlocked, then get a private exclusive lock which will prevent readers until you have finished modifying the data.

Comment: @Dave ok great, so it looks like in the addToEnd() function, i'll just need to switch out the RLock() line to Lock() and the RUnlock() line to Unlock(). Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program allocates a single structure (`j` in the `for j:= range` loop) and repeatedly overwrites it with the contents read from the channel.

This results in the same variable (`j`, at a fixed memory location) being added to the list multiple times.

Consider modifying the channel to be a channel of pointers.

In `main()`

```
cha := make(chan *Node)
```

Then for `makeNodes()`
Each time a new node is created (via `Node{}`), a *new* Node pointer is placed into the channel.

```
func makeNodes(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan *Node) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {
        tmp := Node{Data: i, Next: nil}
        ch <- &tmp
    }
    <-ctx.Done()
    return
}
```

The following will now correctly add each unique Node pointer to the list.

```
go func() {
    for j := range cha {
        list.addToEnd(j)
    }
}()
```

Also, you may find not all entities make it to the list or are read from the channel.  Your method for synchronizing the producer (`makeNodes()`) and consume (`for j:= range`) needs work.